# Let $T$ and $T'$ be topologies on set $X$ so that $ T \subset T'$. If $(X, T') $ is path connected, is then $(X, T) $ path connected?

Tags: general-topology

Let $T$ and $T'$ be topologies on set $X$ so that $ T \subset T'$. If $(X, T') $ is path connected, is then $(X, T) $ path connected?

I am not sure how to prove that it is true but cannot find a counterexample. Any hint helps!

Comment: Hint: given a, b in X, use the same continuous map [path] f from [0, 1]->X with endpoints a and b that you would for T’, and recall that continuous<=>the preimage of an open set is open. All open sets in T are already open in T’, so...